# Should all buttons contain a reference to the controller in MVC code (C++)?

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, structure

I'm trying to figure out the best (cleanest) way to structure some code in C++ for an application I'm building. I think MVC makes sense as the way to go, but after a fair amount of research I'm not totally clear I'm doing things the right way.

Here's an example to illustrate my question:

**Model**

I have a class which contains drawing data called `Canvas`. An example function, used to clear the current contents of the canvas, is `ClearCanvas()`.

Ultimately, I want a button in the interface to be able to call this function and clear the canvas.

**Controller**

I have a controller class for the canvas: `CanvasController`

The controller creates and then holds a reference to a canvas object: `CurrentCanvas`

The controller also creates the view: `CanvasView` and then sets a reference to itself on the view: `CurrentCanvasView->SetControllerRef(this);`

**View**

The view is made up of a series of nested classes that define the UI. For example, the hierarchy leading to the button in question might be something like this:

```
CanvasView
-VerticalBox
--HorizontalBox
---Button
```

During the view's constructor, a reference to the controller is passed from the view to all interactive elements, eg. `NewButton->SetControllerRef(this->GetControllerRef());`

**Button Pressed**

So now when the button is pressed, it can function like this:

```
void ClearCanvasButton::OnButtonPressed()
{
    Controller->CurrentCanvas->ClearCanvas();
}
```

So my general question is: **(1)** does this seem like the right way to be doing things, or badly structured?

Also **(2)**: Should the controller be encapsulating the canvas functions, for example:

```
void CanvasController::ClearCanvas()
{
    CurrentCanvas->ClearCanvas();
}
```

Such that the function on the button could simply be:

```
void ClearCanvasButton::OnButtonPressed()
{
    Controller->ClearCanvas();
}
```

I'm just not sure whether it's correct to essentially be passing down a reference to the controller to all elements of the view which ultimately want to change the model, or whether there is a cleaner way.

Apologies if the question has been asked a thousand times in a thousand different ways, I have been searching around trying to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a *class* `ClearCanvasButton`, if your `Button` class contains a member like

```
std::function<void()> onButtonPressed;
```

or [similar](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/signals2.html), rather than

```
virtual void onButtonPressed() {};
```

You then pass a lambda that references the controller

```
CanvasView::CanvasView()
{
    // make the widgets
    Button.onButtonPressed = [Controller](){ Controller->ClearCanvas(); };
}
```

Comment: Lambdas are new to me, so I'm still wrapping my head around your answer. But it seems to solve the problem of passing a reference to the controller all the way down to every individual button in the UI, which definitely seems neater.
Ah, your edit just cleared something up for me, I think. The 'Controller' in the captures section of the lambda is the pointer to the controller on the View, is that right?

Comment: @kinkersnick yes. each lambda is of a unique class whose data members are the captures, and whose only member function is `operator()`